# VS Code can not found Angular component in *.HTML

Tags: angular

All my component in Angular frontend is undefined with message

```
(element) XXXXX: HTMLElement
'XXXX' is not a known element:
1. If 'XXXX' is an Angular component, then verify that it is part of this module.
2. To allow any element add 'NO_ERRORS_SCHEMA' to the '@NgModule.schemas' of this component.ngtsc(-998001)
```

[image: Undefined component]

in other case component defined correctly

```
@Component({
    selector: 'grid',
    templateUrl: './grid.component.html',
    styles: [`
        .vacation_today {
        background-color: #b6afaf;
    }
    `]
})
export class GridComponent implements OnChanges, OnInit {
```

and in runtime frontend working correctly.

Any my attempt to add additional definition to *.ts like

```
import { GridComponent } from './../../../../components/grid/grid.module';
```

was unsuccessful. And all my code marked as red on the right panel.
How to fix this error message?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All the angular components should be either standalone (Ng 14.2+) or part.of NgModules.
On both case feature component, which using you grid component in html template, must mention grid,s NgModule (or grid itself if it's standalone) in the imports section

```
@Component({
imports: [
GridModule,
...
```

Or

```
@NgModule({
imports: [
GridModule,
...
```

Comment: You are right, of course. But why I still can not remove errors? I have add line <import { GridComponent } from "@components/grid/grid.component";> to file \src\app\pages\client\customers\forms\addOrEditCustomerDialog.component.ts and my file \src\app\components\grid\grid.component.ts containes definition <export class GridComponent>, but I still see errors on file \src\app\pages\client\customers\forms\addOrEditCustomerDialog.component.html - WHY? Why I see warning "'GridComponent' is declared but its value is never read." in line <import { GridComponent } ...> What I doing wrong?

Comment: You should add gridModule to the imports section of module which contains declaration of addOrEditCustomerDialog.component

Comment: imports: {GridModule} inside section @Component give me error <Argument of type '{ selector: string; templateUrl: string; imports: { GridModule: typeof GridModule; }; }' is not assignable to parameter of type 'Component'.
  Object literal may only specify known properties, and 'imports' does not exist in type 'Component'.ts(2345)
'imports' is only valid on a component that is standalone.(-992010)>

Comment: You should add GridModule not to the Component, but to the NgModule of this Component

Comment: Thank you, Finally I have understanding what exactly I need to do.